# No GRUB menu on boot - PC directly boots to Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, grub

I have ubuntuGNOME 14.04 alongside windows 8.1. I've been using it for about a year now. Earlier today, I noticed that GRUB OS selection menu doesn't appear anymore. In order to rectify the issue I booted into my pc with a live USB (ubuntuGNOME) and ran GParted : **/dev/sda4** contains my original ubuntu partition.

How do I reset the bootloader?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/87409/i-cant-get-grub-menu-to-show-up-during-boot

Comment: I tried this: Holding shift on boot. Doesn't seem to work. I tried to edit the grub conf file but am not able to access it as super user.